# How to fill a varargs contructor unsing applicationContext beans?

Tags: java, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have a class with a varagrgs contructor

```
public class ScpDataProvider {
------------
    public ScpDataProvider(DataStore... datastores) {
        for(DataStore d : datastores) {
            if(d.type.equals("SQL"))
                initSqlConnection(d);
            dataStores.AddDataStore(d);
        }
    }
------------
}
```

How to fill the contructor with beans of datastores?
This results in `Attribute "ref" is not allowed here`

```
<bean id="dataService"
      class="com.fressnapf.sdk.dataaccess.services.impl.ScpDataProvider">
    <constructor-arg>
        <array>
            <bean ref="dataStore" />
            <bean ref="dataStore2" />
        </array>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use list of refs:

```
<bean id="dataService" class="com.fressnapf.sdk.dataaccess.services.impl.ScpDataProvider">
<constructor-arg>
    <list>
         <ref bean="dataStore" />
         <ref bean="dataStore2" />
    </list>
</constructor-arg>
```

Comment: this should be `<ref bean="dataStore" />`. Please change. But it worked!

Comment: oops, didn't notice it. Thanks! :)